# Programmatically get children of document library using recursion

Tags: sharepoint, recursion, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I need to recurse through the contents of a document library and display them on a webpage using MVC. However I get the following error when trying to run my code: " **The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested**."

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DefaultModel model = new DefaultModel();


            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("MySPSite"))
            {
                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("DocumentLibrary");
                Folder rootFolder = list.RootFolder;

                IEnumerable<SharePointItemBaseModel> items = ProcessFolder(rootFolder);
                model.items.AddRange(items);
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        public IEnumerable<SharePointItemBaseModel> ProcessFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            List<SharePointItemBaseModel> listItems = new List<SharePointItemBaseModel>();
            foreach (Folder childFolder in folder.Folders)
            {
                FolderModel folderModel = new FolderModel();
                IEnumerable<SharePointItemBaseModel> childFolders = ProcessFolder(childFolder,context);
                folderModel.Items.AddRange(childFolders);
                listItems.Add(folderModel);
            }

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in folder.Files)
            {
                DocumentModel documentModel = new DocumentModel();
                documentModel.Name = file.Title;
                documentModel.modifiedBy = file.ModifiedBy.ToString();
                listItems.Add(documentModel);
            }

            return listItems;
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself.

In my recursive method I just used

context.Load(folder.Folders);

and

context.Load(folder.Files);

this initialized the collection allowing me to use it in my foreach loops

Comment: I would highly recommend reading this article on the SharePoint Client Object Model; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268193/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Part-1